# Is knowing two matrices have the same eigenvalues sufficient evidence to prove similarity?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, change-of-basis

I feel like a lot of resources imply that

> Matrixes A and B are similar if and only if tr(A) = tr(B) and det(A) = det(B) and the set of eigenvalues for A and the set of eigenvalues for B are the same.

but I haven't been able to confirm this with Google.

Comment: If they have the same eigenvalues then they have the same determinant and trace. Those conditions are superfluous.

Comment: @kyang19 Instead of changing your question so drastically, you should post a new one.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven It's literally the same question though. I'm asking if there's an "iff" for matrix similarity.

Answer (score 4):

No, this is false. Consider the matrices

$M = \begin{pmatrix} 
  1 & 0 \\
  1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

and

$I = \begin{pmatrix} 
  1 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

The two matrices both have the same determinant, trace, and set of eigenvalues. But they are clearly not similar. Because if $M = K^{-1} I K$, then we would have $M = I$.

If you require that both matrices have a basis of eigenvectors and the same eigenvalues (with the same multiplicities) then the matrices are similar - just change basis from one eigenbasis to the other.

Comment: Nicely written (+1)

Comment: So what you're saying is that matrices A and B are similar iff they have the same eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Comment: If they have the same eigenvalues, AND each eigenvalue has the same number of linearly independent eigenvectors in either case, then they are similar.

Comment: @RobertTheTutor I don't think this is true. Counterexample: $A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$. The two matrices have the same eigenvalues: $0$ and $1$, each associated with exactly one eigenvector, but they are not similar. The minimal polynomial of $A$ is $x(x-1)^2$ and the minimal polynomial of $B$ is $x^2(x-1)$. Alternatively, they have different Jordan normal forms.

Comment: Ah, yes, you are correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If the underlying vector space is one-dimensional, then yes. Otherwise, no.

Counter-example in the latter case is the zero matrix and any non-zero [nilpotent matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilpotent_matrix), i.e. a matrix $N$ such that $N^k=0$ for a positive integer $k > 1$. Both have only zero as the eigenvalue and consequently have zero trace and zero determinant, but are not similar since the only matrix similar to the zero matrix is the zero matrix itself.

Answer (score 0):

Working over the complex numbers, your two matrices will be similar if and only if they have the same Jordan canonical form. (This is a bit more subtle than saying the algebraic and geometric multiplicities of each eigenvalue have to agree, although in some cases that will be enough.)