# How to prove if two matrices are similar without explicitly finding the basis matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inverse, change-of-basis

My understanding is that two matrices A and B are similar if and only if there exists some other matrix M such that A = MBM<sup>-1</sup>.

Is there a way to prove that two matrices are similar **without** knowing exactly what the basis matrix is? Because obviously if we did, then the "proof" would be a trivial one.

Specifically I'd like to know how [the guy in this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LKMGo8G7-vk)  comes up with similar matrices off the top of his head without explicitly finding the basis matrix.

Comment: Welcome to MSE ^_^ You can compute the [Jordan Canonical Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) of both and see if they're the same (up to reordering of blocks).

Comment: How you go about proving it depends on what you do know.  Saying you don't know the basis matrix doesn't give us anything to go on.  Not every pair of matrices $A,B$ are similar, so we need more information about them.

Comment: @hardmath

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LKMGo8G7-vk

I want to know how this guy comes up with similar matrices off the top of his head without explicitly finding the basis matrix.

Comment: @kyang19 You may give the examples in the question.

Comment: Observe that I already answered your question in [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4051890/is-knowing-two-matrices-have-the-same-eigenvalues-sufficient-evidence-to-prove-s). Did you read it?

Comment: I have at least moved your clarifying remark (and its link) into the body of your Question.  The lecturer in that 2015 online video is Dr. Gilbert Srang, well known in the field of numerical methods and especially methods that use linear algebra.

Comment: Thanks, @hardmath. Fixed.

Comment: To answer your question, any of us who know linear algebra well (and certainly those who teach it all the time and have written textbooks) can write down these examples without a second of thought. With *repeated* eigenvalues and in sizes larger than $2$, we will need to prepare ahead of time to do all but the most obvious examples. So, if you watch my videos, you'll see that for the interesting examples I *do* copy a matrix off a piece of paper (my homework assignment preparing for the lecture).

Answer (score 1):

al eigenvalues are roots of the characteristic polynomial, let's call it $f(x).$

It is possible to test for multiple roots by simply finding the polynomial gcd of $f(x)$ and the derivative $f'(x)$

If $f(x)$ has no multiple roots, and $A,B$ are two matrices that have the same characteristic $f(x),$  then they are similar. In particular, both diagonalize, and the diagonal entries agree.

Now, suppose that there are repeated roots, same for the two matrices. If the minimal polynomials do not agree, the matrices are not similar. The degree of the $(x- \lambda )$ term in the minimal polynomial is the size of the largest Jordan block for that eigenvalue $\lambda$

As the size of the matrices gets larger, there are more and more possibilities of distinct Jordan forms. Which is to say, if the characteristic polynomials and minimal polynomials agree, there may still be room for the matrices to fail to be similar.

Answer (score 0):

For two-by-two matrices $A,B$, if the traces and the same, and if the determinants are the same, then at least the characteristic polynomials are the same. Even then, there is still the risk that one has a non-trivial Jordan block, while the other is diagonalizable, and it's maybe not generally easy to distinguish.

An approach for bigger matrices, which already needs some hand computation, is to verify that the trace of $A^n$ is equal to the trace of $B^n$, for $n=1,2,3,\ldots$ up to the size of the matrices. This proves that the characteristic equations are the same. There is still the possibility that the Jordan blocks are different...